# Is it possible to capture the values of variables local to a Delphi anonymous method/closure?

Tags: delphi, closures, anonymous-methods

One of the interesting aspects of Delphi's implementation of anonymous methods
/closures is the ability to capture the state of variables local to the routine
from which the anon method is called.  This is nicely described in one of Marco Cantu's books (Delphi 2009?).

My question is, is there a way to similarly capture the values of variables
which are local to the anonymous method itself?

To hopefully illustrate what I mean, consider the following code snippet,
which does *not* do what I mean:

```
type

  TMemoProc = reference to procedure(Memo: TMemo; StepNo : Integer);

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  [...]
  private
    procedure Process(Memo: TMemo; StepNo: Integer);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    MemoProc : TMemoProc;
    procedure CreateMemoProc;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 3 do
    MemoProc(Memo1, i);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateMemoProc;
  MemoProc(Memo1, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Process(Memo : TMemo; StepNo : Integer);
var
  Count : Integer;
begin
  if StepNo = 0 then
    Count := 1
  else
    Inc(Count);
  Memo.Lines.Add(Self.Name + ' ' +Format('stepno: %d, count: %d', [StepNo, Count]));
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateMemoProc;
begin
  MemoProc :=
    procedure (Memo : TMemo; StepNo : Integer)
    var
      Count : Integer;
    begin
      if StepNo = 0 then
        Count := 1
      else
        Inc(Count);
      Memo.Lines.Add(Format('stepno: %d, count: %d', [StepNo, Count]));
    end;
end;
```

Click Button1 a few times and it's no particular surprise that the numbers inserted
change, as you'd expect from he fact that Delphi doesn't implicitly initialize
simple variables on the stack.

But I'm wondering whether someone can think of an ingenious way to
capture the anon method's local variables between invocations of it.

Fwiw, the reason I'm wondering about this is that there are use-cases where
there need to be typically two invocations of the anon method, one to do some
initialization and one to do some iteration, and the most concise way of coding
would be if the anon method's local variables could somehow be captured.

The sort of use-case I have in mind is writing some general purpose code to iterate a dataset, where it would be handy to specify a boolean function which determines by reference to a row's field values whether a particular dataset row should be processed and another that defines what should be done to the row when the boolean func returns true.

In a tradition implementation, one could specify the fields as DataSet.FieldByName('xxx'), but where many fields and/or many rows are involved, that can be highly inefficient.

So the agenda behind my q is basically to be able to specify the fields involved in an initialization invocation of the anon method, and then to use them directly (as by DataSet11FieldCatflap, rather than DataSet.FieldByName('Catflap').  I have pondered using a containerized list of fields to carry across between the initialization invocation and the itertation one, but it seems "unsatisfying" to me.

Comment: Local variables are captured by the anonymous method. If you want to capture the local variables of the anonymous method itself, then I suppose you've already tried the obvious technique of using an anonymous method? That is, nested anonymous methods, each one capturing the local variables of its enclosing scope.

Comment: Anonymous methods are the only thing that performs variable capture. That's your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the interest Rob.  Yes, I had wondered whether something like nesting might do it, but ran out of mental steam when it came to finding a way to express it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Indeed, but I haven't been able to come up with a way to express an implementation.  Hence, I asked ...

Comment: And what would happen if the anonymous method is called a third time? Do the initialization again? Or do it only once and then forever do the iteration?

Comment: @StefanGlienke:  That's the reason for the StepNo param of my example code, so as to determine that the initialization should occur or not.

Comment: Ok, then what? Pass the stepno or not? If the anonymous method itself tracks it then I won't need to pass it anymore.

Comment: @StefanGlienke:  I've edited my q to include the sort of use-case I have in mind, which may better illustrate why a solution is maybe not as straightforward as one might hope (at least, not for me!).

Comment: I wonder if you read this article (and part 2) yet: http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2010/08/06/a-magical-gathering-part-1/

Answer (score 4):

Anonymous methods capture the state of local variables from their enclosing scope. If the method's implementation requires more state, then declare more local variables in the enclosing scope, even if they're only ever used in the anonymous method's scope.

In your case, that would mean declaring and initializing `Count` in the `CreateMemoProc` method instead of inside the anonymous method stored in `MemoProc`.

In general, it may be unsightly and confusing to have variables declared seemingly in the wrong scope. To avoid this, you can use a method factory whose sole job is to generate anonymous-method instances. Then any oddities about where variables are declared are limited to that one function, so the purpose is clear. You pretty much have that in `CreateMemoProc` already, but if it were up to me, it would be a standalone function rather than a method of the form:

```
function CreateMemoProc: TMemoProc;
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  Count := 0;
  Result := procedure (Memo : TMemo; StepNo : Integer)
    begin
      if StepNo = 0 then
        Count := 1
      else
        Inc(Count);
      Memo.Lines.Add(Format('stepno: %d, count: %d', [StepNo, Count]));
    end;
end;
```

The `Count` variable is local to `CreateMemoProc`, and it's used in the anonymous method, the the anonymous method captures it. Each invocation of `CreateMemoProc` creates a new copy of `Count`, so each anonymous method knows how many times it's been called.

But I get the impression that you don't really want to include a `StepNo` parameter in your method. Instead, you want the method to "know" whether it's been called already. In that case, we can augment `Count` with a flag:

```
type
  TMemoProc = reference to procedure(Memo: TMemo);

function CreateMemoProc: TMemoProc;
var
  Count: Integer;
  Initialized: Boolean;
begin
  Count := 0;
  Initialized := False;
  Result := procedure(Memo: TMemo)
    begin
      if not Initialized then begin
        Count := 0;
        Initialized := True;
      end;
      Inc(Count);
      Memo.Lines.Add(Format('count: %d', [Count]));
    end;
end;
```

Comment: For the database use case, you could pass an array of field names into the method factory. The anonymous method could refer to that array parameter, thus capturing it, and use the demonstrated flag technique to determine whether it needs to fetch any field-reference objects.

Comment: *Anonymous methods capture the state of local variables from their enclosing scope.* This is misleading a little. Anon methods capture variables and not values.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that can capture variables is an anonymous method. You want to have two anonymous methods that capture the same variable. Which means that you need to create the anonymous methods in a single method so that the anonymous methods can capture the same local variable. Like this:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

procedure PerformCapture(InitialValue: Integer; out Getter: TFunc<Integer>;
  out Setter: TProc<Integer>);
var
  Value: Integer;
begin
  Value := InitialValue;

  Getter := function: Integer
    begin
      Result := Value;
    end;

  Setter := procedure(AValue: Integer)
    begin
      Value := AValue;
    end;
end;

var
 Getter: TFunc<Integer>;
 Setter: TProc<Integer>;

begin
  PerformCapture(42, Getter, Setter);
  Writeln(Getter());
  Setter(666);
  Writeln(Getter());
  Setter(-17);
  Writeln(Getter());
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output**

```
42
666
-17
```

Obviously I've written very simple anonymous methods returned as `Getter` and `Setter` but you clearly have the freedom to write methods of arbitrary complexity. Indeed you don't need to implement everything directly in the `Getter` and `Setter` anonymous methods. You could forward the method to some other part of your code, passing the captured variable.

Anonymous methods are great for simple captures of state. But you are not compelled to use anonymous methods in order to carry state from one method call to the next. You can use more traditional means such as a class which contains the state. You might do well to compare these two possible approaches with a view to selecting the mechanism that leads to the clearer coding.

Comment: Thanks, I will sleep on it.  Coincidentally, it was reading @Stefan's article here http://www.delphifeeds.com/postings/127275-anonymous_method_overloading yesterday that set me wondering about this.